# About algebras such that $ j_a j_b \in \{ -1,0, +1,j_c,-j_c \}$ for all $a,b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, change-of-basis, nonassociative-algebras

Consider a commutative unital algebra $A$ of finite dimension $n>3$ over the reals.
The product is defined such that elements are generated with real number coefficients
$(a_0, \dotsc, a_n) $
for some basis
$\{1, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \}$.

Notice $A$ might be non-associative.

Define "F-nilpotent" as there is a nonzero element $x$ in $A$ such that $(x^2) (x^3) = 0$

Conjecture $B$ :

If the algebra $A$ is not "F-nilpotent", then we can always pick a basis $\{1, j_1, \dotsc, j_n \}$ for our algebra $A$, such that
$ j_a j_b \in \{ -1,0, +1,j_c,-j_c \}$ for all $a,b$ and some $c$ as a function of $a$ and $b$ ($c = f(a,b) $).

1. How to prove or disprove it ? Any counterexamples ?
2. How to compute such a basis ?
3. How does this relate to power-associativity ?

Looks a bit like group theory or linear algebra so maybe those fields help.

Notice this is trivially true for algebras that are isomorphic to copies of the complex numbers such as for instance the bicomplex numbers.

Comment: As a remark, if you want $x^j\neq0$ to hold for every element you will need to provide a definition for the symbol as you do not assume power-associativity, nonetheless, what you mean by 'nilpotent algebra' is 'every element is nilpotent', such algebra is usually called Nilalgebra while Nilpotent algebras are those for which there is an index $k>0$ such that any product of length $k$ ($x_1\ldots x_k$) with any distribution of parenthesis is 0.

Comment: Wikipedia says: A commutative algebra is an associative algebra that has a commutative multiplication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra Thus, if your algebra is commutative, it is also associative.

Comment: @Anixx If the word "ring" or "algebra" occurs without further context, it is indeed usually meant to be associative, and this is what that WP page reflects. However commutativity does not imply associativity for nonassociative algebras. Take the Jordan algebras for an example.

Comment: @2ndYearFreshman between the brackets I clarified ; nonzero elements in $A$. And that is the only restriction on what $x$ may be. However you are correct about the $j$ since power-associativity is not assumed theses are not well defined for $j>3$. I noticed that if $x^4 = 0 $ defined as  $x^2 x^2 = 0$ there is some element $y=x^2$ such that $y^2 = 0$ so it simplifies. I will change the question by making some assumptions. Thank you !

Comment: @2ndYearFreshman I used the F of your name for "F-nilpotent" as a tribute :)

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844838/does-x2x3-neq-0-imply-xx3-neq-0