# Does $(x^2)(x^3) \neq 0$ imply $(x)(x^3) \neq 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence, perfect-powers, nonassociative-algebras

Consider a commutative unital algebra $A$ of finite dimension $n>3$ over the reals.
The product is defined such that elements are generated with real number coefficients
$(a_0, \dotsc, a_n) $
for some basis
$\{1, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \}$.

Also we require $A$ to be a non-associative algebra.
In fact not even power-associative.
(otherwise the question has a trivial answer)

Define "F-nilpotent" as there is a nonzero element $x$ in $A$ such that $(x^2) (x^3) = 0$

Conjecture $C$ :

If the algebra $A$ is not "F-nilpotent", there is no nonzero element $x$ in $A$ such that $(x)(x^3) = 0$.

How to prove or disprove it ? Any counterexamples ?

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4843897/about-algebras-such-that-j-a-j-b-in-1-0-1-j-c-j-c-for-all-a-b

Answer (score 2):

The answer to,

> Does $x^2x^3\ne 0$ imply $xx^3\ne 0$ for elements $x$ of a unital, commutative (non-associative) algebra $A$ of finite dimension $n>3$?

is no. Here is a counterexample.

Let $A$ be the unital, commutative, non-associative algebra of dimension $4$ over a field $F$ (you can take $F=\mathbb{R}$ for your question) with basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$ where the multiplication is as in the table

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
     & 1 & x & x^2  & x^3 \\
\hline
    1 & 1 & x & x^2  & x^3 \\
    x & x & x^2 & x^3  & 0 \\
    x^2 & x^2 & x^3 & 0  & 1 \\
    x^3 & x^3 & 0 & 1  & 0 
\end{array}

Then $xx^3=0$ but $x^2x^3=1\ne 0$.

You have also asked *a different question*, which I understand is

> Suppose there is no non-zero $x\in A$ satisfying $x^2x^3=0$, where $A$ is a unital, commutative (non-associative) algebra of finite dimension $n>3$. Does it follow that there is no non-zero $y\in A$ such that $yy^3= 0$?

This question is different to the one in the title, of course. It is also harder, as you note. I will have a think about this question too.

Comment: Here you take $x$ and its powers as a basis for the algebra.
In the OP $x$ is an element of the algebra, so for instance the element $y = a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3$ where $x$ is your basis here and $a,b,c,d$ are real.  It might still hold but that would require more work to show.

Comment: Mick, I don't follow. $x$ is an element of this algebra. If you like it is the element $x=0+1x+0x^2+0x^3$.

Comment: Also you have it in reverse : you took $x x^3 = 0$ does not imply $x^2 x^3 = 0$ but the question was if $x^2 x^3 = 0 $ implies $x x^3 = 0$.  Thanks for the effort so far.

Comment: the statement is : there is NO $x$ such that ... It does not say " for every $x$ ..."